# Dark pieces in brightened HSV image

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I have an image that I want to make brighter. So I just converted it to HSV and multiplied the V value by the coefficient I need. But there are dark pieces in the out image.
Original image:
[image: original img]
Out image:
[image: out image]
Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


real_4 = cv2.imread('data/data_4_real_cut.jpg')
k = 5

cv2.imshow('orig 4', real_4)
hsv_4 = cv2.cvtColor(real_4, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv_4[:, :, 2] *= k
bgr_again = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_4, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow('orig 4 high', bgr_again)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And as I understood when I multiply V value by needed coefficient it could out of `0 - 255` range. But I'm not sure about it and I didn't find any information about it. And of course the question is - why there are dark pieces in the image? Thanks!

Comment: You need to clip the values. When you multiply, it can go beyond 0-255 in V or S, which causes wrap around so that 256 becomes 0, etc.  So clip your values using `.clip(0,255)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in the image are stored as datatype `np.uint8`, which can only store unsigned 8-bit integers (0-255). When the result of the multiplication exceeds 255, the values will [overflow](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors) into `actual_result % 256`, for example: `np.uint8(266) == (266 % 256) == 10`. To prevent overflow, the result needs to be clipped to a maximum value of 255, for which you could use the [`cv2.multiply`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#multiply) method:

```py
import cv2

from skimage.io import imread

rgb = imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tcDv.jpg")
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

k = 5

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# safe multiplication without overflow
hsv[..., 2] = cv2.multiply(hsv[..., 2], k)

bgr_again = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow("orig 4 high", bgr_again)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This will give the correct output result:

[image: output]